# Exporting voxel sections to raster in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, netcdf, kriging, voxel

I need to perform some algebra in voxel sections resulting from EBK 3D (NetCDF file).

I need to calculate a mean section and standard deviation, and to do that I need to export the sections to raster.

How could I do that in ArcGIS Pro?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Esri staff member Andrew--Johnson at [Export voxel layer sections](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/export-voxel-layer-sections/m-p/1265955/highlight/true#M66431):

> Unfortunately we have not had a chance to work on this as getting
> voxel layers on the web was the higher priority. Currently, we are
> working on performance improvements so this is not in the near term
> plan. If you would prefer to keep track of this I would recommend
> submitting an ArcGIS Idea so I can keep you and others updated on when
> it's in the product plan and when it will be implemented.

Comment: Although is not possible to export the sections to raster, what I did was import the Netcdf file in Python with xarray and calculated the mean and variance in python.